# Converting Megabit to Kilobit in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file out.result that contains

```
73.0Mb
69.7Mb
59.8Mb
71.3Mb
59.7Mb
244Kb
```

I need to convert the Mb values to Kb i.e

```
cat out.result | awk '{ total = $1 * 1000 ; print total }'
```

but that also does it for the value that is already in Kb

```
73000
69700
59800
71300
59700
244000
```

How do I work around this?

Comment: shouldn't be the conversion by 1024?

Comment: @karakfa No, bits aren't counted in multiples of 1024. Bytes are *sometimes* counted in multiples of 1024, which is printed as 1 K*i*B, or [kibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '{print $0 * (/Mb/ ? 1000 : 1)}' file
73000
69700
59800
71300
59700
244
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `b` and use `numfmt`

```
sed 's/b//' inputfile | numfmt --from=si --to-unit=K
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk '
{
  val=substr($0,length($0)-1)
  if(tolower(val)=="mb"){
    $0 *= 1024
  }
}
{
  print $0+0
}' Input_file
```